# Does this function wp_get_nav_menu_object check if a nav menu exists or is supported?

Tags: menus, oop

```
function wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu ) {
if ( ! $menu )
    return false;

$menu_obj = get_term( $menu, 'nav_menu' );

if ( ! $menu_obj )
    $menu_obj = get_term_by( 'slug', $menu, 'nav_menu' );

if ( ! $menu_obj )
    $menu_obj = get_term_by( 'name', $menu, 'nav_menu' );

if ( ! $menu_obj )
    $menu_obj = false;

return $menu_obj;
}
```

I know that [has_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_nav_menu) can be used to check if a nav menu has been assigned to a theme location however not sure what the code above does as the [docs for this function are limited](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_object).

I need to check if the nav menu exists and the theme location is supported by the theme.

Code Source http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_nav_menu_object/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the source code that you posted.

The code attempts to get the menu by ID using `get_term`, then by slug and name using `get_term_by`. If nothing is found it returns `false`, here:

```
if ( ! $menu_obj )
    $menu_obj = false;
```